# Why is there no trace of auxiliary classifiers of the Inception v3 model in Keras?

Tags: python, image, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

When using Inception v3 model in Keras, nor the graph of the network nor the model.summary() indicate the presence of the auxiliary classifiers (as in [Szegedy et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00567).

Why is it so ? Is Keras still using the right architecture but hiding this specificity from the user ? If so, how can we then customize upper layers from the network ? Indeed, we may want the 3 classifiers to have distinct architectures.

Thank you !

Comment: I think I figured it out (at least for transfer learning). Lower layers classifiers are not supposed to be retrained when we do transfer learning. They are mainly present to mitigate gradient vanishing in the lower layers. So for only few layers retraining, the last classifier will be impacted only. However, for deeper modifications of the inception v3, I still do not get it ....